# Add the data of two similar tables in Mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, sum

I have two similar tables with same columns. I just want to add the data of the column of one table with the corresponding data of the column of another table. Thus, form a new table which consists of the sum of individual data of both the tables. 
Would you please help me?

Comment: your question is not clear. do you want a new table with only two columns: one column from one table and one column from another table? ---------- do you want the sum of the data like its numbers? ------------ or do you want all of the individual data from one table combined with all of the individual data from another table all into one single table?

Comment: Dear John,Firstly thank you for your interest. I want all of the individual data from one table combined with all of the individual data from another table all into one single table. Would you please help me ?

Comment: what are the table names? and do you have an ID to join them on? look at my answer and see the general format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this?

```
INSERT INTO myTable 
    SELECT 
        s.salary + t.salary AS salary, 
        s.name 
    FROM table_name s
    JOIN table_name_2 t ON t.name = s.name -- or whatever parameter you use to join the two tables on
```

Comment: Yaa John. Something similar to it. I have name instead of id. That's the only difference. I executed the query but it says ' #1052 - Column 'name' in field list is ambiguous '.

Comment: @CivaBhusal ok i just edited... added table to pull name from since theres two `name` columns ------ what are the two table names?

Answer (score 0):

you can do like

```
insert into newTable select * from table1;
insert into NewTable select * from table2;
```

this will insert two tables data to new Table.

Comment: Thank for the answer.But perhaps, I couldn't make you clear. I mean the sum. I have table1 with columns name and salary. I have table2 with same columns name and salary. If the data for table1 is 2000 and table2 is 4000. Then the new table should contain 6000 as the salary. Did I make you clear now?